# how to define a host with https in action_mailer.default_url_options

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, configuration, actionmailer

ActionMailer provides a way to define the host to use with resource helpers:

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => "example.com" }
```

I can't find a way to force this to **https**.

Comment: did you find an answer to this?

Comment: No, but it's not a big problem for me, since I always do a redirect from http -> https on my server.

Comment: Found this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5760867/449610

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rails mailer edit\_user\_url uses http not https](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5760767/rails-mailer-edit-user-url-uses-http-not-https)

Answer (score 69):

All you have to do it add "protocol" to the default url options:

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'example.com', :protocol => 'https'}
```

Dazpinto was right - linking to a duplicate question with the answer: [Rails mailer edit_user_url uses http not https](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5760767/rails-mailer-edit-user-url-uses-http-not-https/5760867#5760867)